# where do i receive the objects i sent from php in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I have this php code and i don't know how can i put all those arrays i send at the end of the code into only one array so that i can send this array to android ?

```
$username = $_POST["username"];  
$locations_string = "";
$names = array();
$response1= array();
$response2= array();
$user_record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$value = mysql_fetch_array($user_record);
$userlocation = $value['location'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AllFriendsExceptBlocked WHERE username ='$username'       ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
array_push($names , $value["friendname"]);

echo $row['friendname']. " - ". $row['location'];
echo "<br />";
}
for($i=0; $i < count($names) ; $i++){
$friend = $names[$i];
$user_record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AllFriendsExceptBlocked WHERE     friendname='$friend' ");
$value = mysql_fetch_array($user_record);
$locations_string = $locations_string . "," . $value['location'];

}
$response["message"] = "send locations of friends in AllFriendsExceptBlocked";
$response1["panicedUserLocation"] = $userlocation;
$response2["locations"] = $locations_string;

echo json_encode($response);
json_encode($response);
echo json_encode($response2);
json_encode($response2);
echo json_encode($response2);
json_encode($response2);
```

now how can i receive those responses i sent from the php in android?

Answer (score 0):

from the http call  where you are getting response try to convert the response to json object. example.

```
InputStream JsonStream=responce.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JsonStream));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
{

    builder.append(line);
}
String JSONdata = builder.toString();
Log.i("JsonData",JSONdata);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSONdata);
```

Comment: okay am doing it wrong i should only send one array i cannot send all these arrays! so any idea of how to bind all these responses together?

Comment: you can have nested array in one array like : {{},{}}